# How to disable an input dynamically with Angular 7

Tags: html, angular, input, angular7

I'm trying to disable an input depending on the value taken from the Component.ts

In my `component.ts` file I have this value

```
disName = false;
```

And in my HTML I have these elements

```
Name: <input type="text"
             value="name"
             size="15"
             id="name"
             name="firstName"
             [(ngModel)]="aproverFirstName"
             [attr.disable]="disName=='true' ? true : null">
```

What looking for is that if my value on the `component.ts` is false, then in the html file the input element should change to disable depending on the value.

I've also tried this `[disable]="disName"`

I'm using Angular 7, thanks a lot!

Comment: Camila, disName is a boolean, so `[attr.disable]="disName ? true : null">` (not put =='true')

Comment: it's `disabled`, not `disable`

Comment: I have this:  [attr.disabled]="!inactive ? true : null"  with inactive set as false in the TS file. I use a button to change the value. This works but not on the initial state.

When I open page, my input field is editable, only when I change to true and back to false does it disable the field. Any idea how to change this?

Answer (score 5):

You should do like this:

```
<input type="text"
             value="name"
             size="15"
             id="name"
             name="firstName"
             [(ngModel)]="aproverFirstName"
             [disabled]="disName">
```

But, I prefer to use `@angular/forms` in Angular, Then you can init the form like this:

HTML:

```
<input type="text"
                 value="name"
                 size="15"
                 id="name"
                 formControlName="firstName">
```

Typescript:

Init form:

```
this.sampleForm= this.fb.group({
      firstName: [{ value: '', disabled: true }, Validators.required]
});
```

Control enable and disable by:

```
this.sampleForm.controls.firstName.enable();
this.sampleForm.controls.firstName.disable();
```

Answer (score 2):

The attribute you're looking for is [disabled].

```
<input type="text" [disabled]="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  <input type="text" [disabled]="!disName">
```

the condition has to be true.

Are you putting this "input" tag in component.html?